Is there a way to display two TextFields used as custom search bars in top navigation bar directly under each other?
Trying to display two custom search bars under each other in the top navigation bar using SwiftUI and I can only get one to work in top navigation bar and one in bottom bar.
.toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                HStack {
                    TextField(" Enter book title", text: $searchTextTitle)
                        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .light, design: .default))
                        .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous))
                    Button(action: {
                        fetchLatestBooks()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease")
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 350, height: 26)
                } //end toolbaritem
            } //end toolbar
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                HStack {
                    TextField(" Enter book author", text: $searchTextAuthor)
                        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .light, design: .default))
                        .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous))
                }
                .frame(width: 350, height: 26)
                }//end toolbaritem
            } //end toolbar

Using .navigationBarLeading for both places them side by side
